# Groovy convert from List to var args for method call

Tags: list, groovy, variadic-functions

I am using a plugin that provides email functionality as follows:

```
class SendSesMail {

    //to
    void to(String ... _to) { 
        this.to?.addAll(_to)
        log.debug "Setting 'to' addresses to ${this.to}"
    }

}
```

The documentation states the class is called as follows:

```
sesMail {
    from "from@a.com"
    replyTo "reply@a.com"
    to "t@a.com", "t@b.com", "t@c.com"
    subject "Subject"
    html "Body HTML"
}
```

In the code a `List` of addresses is built up and I'm trying to figure out how to convert this list to the var args expected by the method.

Converting to a `String` concatenated with "," doesn't work as this is an invalid email address. I need to be able to separate each List item into a separate parameter to avoid having to iterate over the List and send each email individually.

Comment: Are you getting an error with the code above?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Probably the spread operator, `*`, is what you're looking for:

```
def to(String... emails) {
    emails.each { println "Sending email to: $it"}
}

def emails = ["t@a.com", "t@b.com", "t@c.com"]
to(*emails)
// Output: 
// Sending email to: t@a.com
// Sending email to: t@b.com
// Sending email to: t@c.com
```

Notice that the parentheses on the method call to `to` are mandatory, as otherwise `to *emails` would be parsed as a multiplication. Bad choice of overloaded grammar symbols IMO =P

Comment: I've never seen the spread operator used in that context and I couldn't get it to work in a simple example - can you point out some other examples of using it?

Comment: Shouldn't the code in the question run as it is anyway (without the spread operator)? eg:  try: `def a( String... p ) { p.each { println it } } ; a 'a', 'b', 'c'`

Comment: @tim_yates Yes. But i _think_ the OP meant that that code snippet was from the documentation, and what he wanted to do was to call the method with arguments that came from a List.

Comment: @SteveD [This](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy) is the only reference to the spread operator used in method calls that i could find in the Groovy documentation. The code in this answer should run in the Groovy Console as is.